# Admin action that changes related OneToOne data

Tags: django, django-admin, one-to-one

I have a model like so:

```
class Party(models.Model):
    assignedTo=models.ForeignKey('Personnel', verbose_name='Assigned To', limit_choices_to={'is_staff_member':True}, blank=True, null=True)

class Person(models.Model):
    party = models.OneToOneField(Party, editable=False)
```

I'm trying to create an admin action that would allow me to bulk assign a Personnel member to multiple Persons. My assumption would be to create an action like so:

```
def bulk_assign_Kristi(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    queryset.update(party__assignedTo='8')
```

But [Django doesn't seem to allow OneToOnes within `update()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once). Any ideas how to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will work:

```
queryset.update(party__assignedTo__id=8)
```

UPDATE: Included Jingo's typo fix from the comment.

Comment: When this works it would be queryset.update(party__assignedTo__id=8)

Comment: Nope. I get `Person has no field named 'party__assignedTo__id'`. Thanks for the input though!